# Dataflow job retains old error state after updating

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When I was submitting my Dataflow job using DataflowRunner (I was using streaming job with Pub/Sub source), I made a mistake when defining the execution parameter of the BQ table name (let's say that the wrong table name is project-A) and the job threw some error. Then I updated the job using --update command with the correct table name, but the job then threw some error again i.e. the error told me that I am still using project-A as the BQ table name.

In short, this is what I was doing looks like:

1. I submit a Dataflow job

```sh
python main.py \
 --job_name=dataflow-job1 \
 --runner=DataflowRunner \
 --staging_location=gs://project-B-bucket/staging \
 --temp_location=gs://project-B-bucket/temp \
 --dataset=project-A:table-A
```

2. I got errors as project-A:table-A was not the correct dataset

```sh
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Access Denied: Dataset project-A:table-A: User does not have bigquery.datasets.get permission for dataset project-A:table-A.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Access Denied: Dataset project-A:table-A: User does not have bigquery.datasets.get permission for dataset project-A:table-A.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "accessDenied"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

3. I updated the job using --update

```sh
python main.py \
 --job_name=dataflow-job1 \
 --runner=DataflowRunner \
 --staging_location=gs://project-B-bucket/staging \
 --temp_location=gs://project-B-bucket/temp \
 --dataset=project-B:table-B \
 --update
```

4. Then I got the same error as before (point 2)

Why it seems like the old state of the job still retained? I thought that if Dataflow detect error on the job it will not process the pipeline and the Pub/Sub will not be ACKed and the pipeline will re-started.

Update 2020-12-08:
This is how I pass the parameter arguments:

```py
class MyOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--dataset')
...
class WriteToBigQuery(beam.PTransform):
    def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (pcoll
                | 'WriteBQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            '{0}.my_table'.format(self.name),
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(flags=argv)
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
    my_args = pipeline_options.view_as(MyOptions)
    ...
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        ...
        # I wrapped the BQ write component inside a PTransform class
        output | 'WriteBQ' >> WriteToBigQuery(my_args.dataset)
```

Comment: can you show how you pass the pipeline option to the BQ transform?

Comment: @Pablo I have update my question with the code I used to pass pipeline option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the pipeline parameters with you update the dataflow streaming jobs. You can only update the transforms of your pipeline.

Comment: If that's the case, what is the best approach to deal with such kind of problem? What I've done was canceling the job (I can't drained it because of the error) and deploy the new one with the correct parameter.

Comment: Yes, and because the PubSub messages aren't acknowledge, they are kept and resubmitted to the new job creation, to not loose data.